# Java Stream: Merge value of list with values of nested list to one list

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following classes:

```
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public classAccount {
    List<AccountRole> accountRoles = new ArrayList<>();    
    List<AccountRole> getAccountRoles() { return accountRoles };
}
    
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AccountRole {
    List<Operation> operations = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Operation> getAllowedOperations( return operations);
    String accountRole;
    String getAuthority() { return accountRole; }
}
    
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Operation {
    String operation;
    String getAuthority( return operation; )
}
```

I managed it to collect all authorities of the operations like:

```
account.getAccountRoles().stream()
    .flatMap(accountRole -> accountRole.getAllowedOperations().stream().map(operation -> operation.getAuthority()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

I didn't manage it to collect the authorities of account roles and the operations in one stream and merge them to the result list. Is there a possibility?

Comment: @YCF_L I know, its just an example. I can also add the complete Code Snippet...

Comment: Well, you could try something like `flatMap(accountRole -> Stream.concat(Stream.of(getAuthority()), accountRole.getAllowedOperations().stream().map(operation -> operation.getAuthority())))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`Stream.concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat(java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.stream.Stream)):

> Creates a lazily concatenated stream whose elements are all the elements of the first stream followed by all the elements of the second stream.

```java
account.getAccountRoles().stream()
    .flatMap(role -> Stream.concat(
            role.getAllowedOperations().stream().map(Operation::getAuthority),
            Stream.of(role.getAuthority())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Unless you're doing something more complex than just putting them all in a list, then it's probably better to not build a combined stream. Just independently add them to a list:

```java
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (AccountRole role : account.getAccountRoles()) {
    for (Operation operation : role.getAllowedOperations()) {
        result.add(operation.getAuthority());
    }
    result.add(role.getAuthority();
}
```

Comment: For me its' not working to add a Stream.concat in the flatMap, the second solution is of course the easier solution! :)

Comment: I made a mistake, the solution is working! Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
        .flatMap(accountRole -> {
                    List<String> roles = accountRole.getAllowedOperations().stream()
                            .map(Operation::getAuthority)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                    roles.add(accountRole.getAuthority());
                    return roles.stream();
                }
        )
```

You can also create a method to get roles as this :

```
private Stream<String> getRoles(AccountRole accountRole) {
    List<String> roles = accountRole.getAllowedOperations().stream()
            .map(Operation::getAuthority)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    roles.add(accountRole.getAuthority());
    return roles.stream();
}
```

and then, you can just call :

```
.flatMap(this::getRoles)
```